# Itemplate properties not available as attributes

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, custom-controls, itemplate

I've added an ITemplate to Telerik's RadGrid control called SearchMenuTemplate ala:

```
    public class AbsRadGrid : RadGrid
{

    private ITemplate _ItemTemplate;
    [PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty)]
    [TemplateContainer(typeof(searchBar))]
    public ITemplate SearchMenuTemplate
    {
        get { return _ItemTemplate; }// get
        set { _ItemTemplate = value; }// set
    }
}
```

And the Template class looks something like (mandatory override methods like createchildcontrol have been omitted for brevity):

```
[ParseChildren(true)]
class searchBar : CompositeControl, INamingContainer
{
    public string rbStartsWithText { get; set; }
}
```

Now, in the source control window the RadGrid control sees the Template. But rbStartsWithText isn't an attribute on the node.

I want to see something like this (note: abs prefix is registered in the markup):

```
    <abs:AbsRadGrid ID="rg" runat="server">
    <SearchMenuTemplate rbStartsWithText="Starts With" />
</abs:AbsRadGrid>
```

Instead rbStartsWithText is throwing a green squiggly and telling me it's not a valid attribute of SearchMenuTemplate.

Answer (score 0):

Your `SearchMenuTemplate` property is of a type `ITemplate` which hasn't public properties, so IntelliSense just cannot offer any attribute for your `<SearchMenuTemplate>` tag.

To be able to add a custom property you should implement `ITemplate` interface (`InstantiateIn` method) and add desired property there:

```
public class YourCustomTemplate : ITemplate
{
    public string rbStartsWithText { get; set; }

    public void InstantiateIn(Control container)
    {
        HtmlGenericControl div = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
        div.InnerText = rbStartsWithText;
        container.Controls.Add(div);
    }
}
```

then you could use it your custom grid:

```
public class AbsRadGrid : RadGrid
{
    [PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty)]
    public YourCustomTemplate  SearchMenuTemplate { get; set; }
}
```

and finally:

```
<abs:AbsRadGrid ID="rg" runat="server">
    <SearchMenuTemplate rbStartsWithText="Starts With" />
</abs:AbsRadGrid>
```